# Whats the best way to present a list to a user where each item on the list starts an Activity when selected?

Tags: android, list, android-activity, android-intent

I am on my first Android application and I am on a timeline so details and examples will be useful since my knowledge is still minimal.

I want my first screen to present the user with a list of activities to choose from. In my situation it is a recipe app where the user first chooses the type of food, such as, Beef, Chicken, or Pork. I want the application to launch an activity depending on the list item that the user clicked on.

I am not sure if I should use a list view, a text view, a scroll view, a list activity, an activity group... I need help please.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: it sounds like a choice interaction design rather than a programming issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use a ListActivity as your base class.  As your class extends ListActivity you can use the event onListItemClick() to interpret the item the user clicks on and launch the appropriate intent.

You can bind your list to an Array of your foods.  There are plenty of examples to be found how to construct the activity, just google for 'listactivity'

I was about to reply to your other post on using the arrays but it seems to have now disappeared.. so my reply to that post is below also

Create a second array that contains just your activity class names, So where you have

```
<string-array name="food_array">
    <item> Beef</item>
    <item>Chicken</item>
    <item>Fish</item>
    <item>Pork</item>
</string-array>
```

Also have a mirroring array that you can access e.g.

```
<string-array name="food_array_activities">
    <item>BeefActivity.class</item>
    <item>ChickenActivity.class</item>
    <item>FishActivity.class</item>
    <item>PorkActivity.class</item>
</string-array>
```

as your onItemClick gives you the position in the list that was clicked you can directly reference the second array to determine the activity name you should use.

Rgds

Comment: This is a good idea, I am having a few problems getting "food_array_activities" into my code. I currently have my string-array as you made them pretty much. I have no problem listing the items from the "food_array" because their nature is a string. But shouldn't position be an attribute of "food_array_activities" wouldn't I need an array list? But I cannot do that by having my activities in a "string-array"

Comment: Your 'position' you receive in the onItemClick will be your index into the array.  

E.g. in onItemClick
// first get resources and load array
Resources res = getResources();
String[] activitiesArray = res.getStringArray(R.array.food_array_activities);

// see what the corresponding activity is..
String selectedActivity = activitiesArray[position];

Comment: Ok so far I have: 
public class foodActivity extends ListActivity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
 
        String[] food = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.food_array);
        final String[] activities = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.activities);
 this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, food));
        final ListView lv = getListView();

Comment: (continued)       
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {      
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {  
                String selectedActivity = activities[position];
                Intent nextActivity = new Intent (foodActivity.this, selectedActivity);
                startActivity(nextActivity);
            }});}}

Comment: (Continued)
On my Intent nextActivity line, eclipse is saying that "The constructor Intent(foodActivity, String) is undefined"

On of the solutions it provides me which will not work is to change String selectedActivity to Class<?> selectedActivity.

Comment: Try this as the second parameter to the Intent constructor must be a Class and not a String..

Intent nextActivity = new Intent (foodActivity.this, Class.forName(selectedActivity));